# How to understand the first element in an object is valid?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I ran `{'1'}[0]`, I got `[0]`.
Why the above statement even is valid? And why the value is 0?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 4):

If we add formatting to the code, you have:

```
{
    '1';
}
[0];
```

A **block** (pointless because no scoping happens within it and it isn't associated with an `if`, `while` or similar) containing a **string** (pointless because nothing is done with it) followed by an **array** with a **number** in it.

The array is the last expression in the code, so the result of evaluating it is logged to the console.

The `{}` isn't an object, and the `[]` isn't a property accessor.

Comment: Awesome explanation!